# Ubuntu 16.04- Annoying .Ink Files -> Leading to shortcuts in Windows: How to Fix?

Tags: 16.04, shortcuts, malware

I've had a look at the answer mentioned previously on AskUbuntu to fix shortcut virus. But, I'm unable to fix it that way.

Whenever I transfer data to the pen drive (on Ubuntu) and use it on a Windows powered system, a shortcut gets created instead and I fix it using the command prompt to retrieve the files.

I've performed a full system scan using Bitdefender and quarantined/deleted them (some failed to delete, so quarantined). And,ClamTk does not seem to work (it shows 0 files scanned and 0 threats found whichever directory I select).

Is there a simpler method in order to get rid of this thing? There are 0 threats according to Bitdefender, but still, the problem exists.

Thanks in advance!

P.S: I'm a newbie who switched permanently from Windows. So, you can avoid being completely geeky and instead link to useful online resources which would help me understand better!

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Ummm... are you saying that Ubuntu got a virus?

Comment: Technically, I'm not that good to point it out as a virus, but it's still a problem ;)

Comment: Can you post the contents of the folder so that I can pin point as to which files to delete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like there is a Windows virus on the flash drive.

Simply format it, and it should get wiped out.

## Warning: this will erase all data on the flash drive!

Open the included Disks application in Ubuntu, select your USB drive, click the gear icon, and then format:

[image]

Tell it to use DOS/MBR partition style.

Then, create a new FAT32 partition that spans the entire disk. Then you should be good to go.

## You should probably reinstall Windows though...

Comment: I formatted the drive, but didn't get "create a new FAT32 partition that spans the entire disk".. Some screenshots would really help!

Thanks for your precious time!

Comment: @ankush - Click the little + button under the volumes chart.

Answer (score 0):

According to your screenshot:

1. IT IS A WINDOWS VIRUS. Specifically speaking 'The Shortcut Virus'.
2. But do not worry all your data is safe inside that unnamed folder.
3. This virus WILL RETURN if you plug your pendrive into a Windows computer that has that virus.
4. The process to removing that virus is by copying all your data (not the virus files such *.ini, etc.) from the unnamed folder to the parent directory of your pendrive. Then delete that folder and the *.Ink file in the parent directory.

Your pendrive now is as good as new. The virus is completely erased.

P. S. :- Please be careful while copying data from the unnamed folder. Make sure to not copy the files related to the virus.

Comment: Thanks for the help! So, my Ubuntu system isn't infected then which causes this problem?
I'll update here after I try the same on another Windows powered system which is free from any kind of viruses.